# How to get variable but not call function

Tags: python, function, variables

i'm trying to get the value from an inside function func2, to put it outside without calling func1 and func2. Here is my program:

```
def func1():
    def func2(x, y, z):
#        global str
        str = "Xin chao`"
#    func2()
#func1()

print("Result:", str)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't call the functions, that variable doesn't exists. You could declare it `global` but it will not take the value `Xin chao` if you don't call those functions

Comment: So is there a way for me to properly pass the str variable only through the func2 function to func1?